# Decode JSON Object in C# without prior knowledge of type

Tags: c#, json

I have some working code:

```
String objstr = "{\"m_children\":[{\"m_children\":null,\"m_name\":\"child0\"},{\"m_children\":null,\"m_name\":\"child1\"}],\"m_name\":\"Root\"}";
byte[] byteArr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objstr);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr);
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Node));

Node obj = (Node)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```

What bugs me is that I have to know the type of the object contained in the string before I decode it. I wanted to send an object encoded in JSON over a TCP pipe, and not have to send extra information about what type the object is.

Comment: json can only serialize plain objects. can't you use some other form of serialization that allows typing?

Comment: [Dynamic?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) @einacio, they specifically asked to "not have to send extra information about what type the object is", which, say, xsd would be.

Comment: so @Almo want magic typing on a static typed language. could send the type as an extra data in the json, but i don't know if c++ can create objets using strings instead of classname php-style

Comment: I was wondering why the serializer doesn't include any type info in its output. I found a place where the .net serializer will, but it seems to be non-standard and won't work with serializers outside .net. And I'm not in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With .NET 4.0 you can use dynamic objects. Why not try out this solution from another question: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-dynamic-object/3806407#3806407)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that once we upgrade to VS2010.

Comment: I think if you're not using VS2010, you'll need to create your own serializer/deserializer using collections, such as Dictionary objects to represent the JSON field names and values.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/fastJSON.aspx

When this library encodes JSON, it gives enough info for completely automatic reparsing.

This doesn't suit my purpose that well though, since it includes a bunch of C#-specific info, and we're working cross-language here.